# Spider only crawling the last url, but not all

Tags: web-scraping, url, scrapy

I want to scrape multiple urls stored in a csv file using Scrapy. My code works(shows no error) but it only scrapes the last url, but not all of them. Here is a picture of my code. Plz tell me what I'm doing wrong. I want to scrape all the urls and save the scraped text together. I have already tried a lot of the suggestions found on StackOverflow. My code-

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from ..items import personalprojectItem


class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'articles'
    with open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Bhavya\\input_urls.csv') as file:
        for line in file:
            start_urls = line

            def start_requests(self):
                request = Request(url=self.start_urls)
                yield request

        def parse(self, response):
            item = personalprojectItem()
            article = response.css('div p::text').extract()
            item['article'] = article
            yield item
```

Comment: Please do not post picture of code. Instead, read what a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) looks like, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Do not post links to images or embed images of code... copy your code into your question.  Please read [ask]

Comment: You are redefining `start urls` for every line in your file with links. You should instead define `start_urls` as a list: [x for x in <file with lines>].

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus that didn't work. It is showing an error - Request url must be str, got list. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `start_urls` is **always** a list. You even define a single url like `start_urls = ['https://www.ocado.com/search?display=5000&entry=frozen']` - for the sake of example. You can drop the `start_requests()` function after defining the start_urls list, and move straight to parsing function(s).

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Thank you. That worked. I have also marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a minimal example of how you can include a list of urls from file in a scrapy project.

We have a text file with the following links, inside the scrapy project folder:

```
https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/nov/18/elon-musk-twitter-engineers-workers-mass-resignation
https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/nov/18/iranian-protesters-set-fire-to-ayatollah-khomeinis-ancestral-home
https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/nov/18/canada-safari-park-shooting-animals-two-charged
```

The spider code looks like this (again, minimal example):

```
import scrapy


class GuardianSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'guardian'
    allowed_domains = ['theguardian.com']
    start_urls = [x for x in open('urls_list.txt', 'r').readlines()]

    def parse(self, response): 
        title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        header = response.xpath('//div[@data-gu-name="standfirst"]//p/text()').get()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'header': header
        }
```

If we run the spider with `scrapy crawl guardian -o guardian_news.json`, we get a JSON file looking like this:

```
[
{"title": "Elon Musk summons Twitter engineers amid mass resignations and puts up poll on Trump ban", "header": "Reports show nearly 1,200 workers left company after demand for \u2018long hours at high intensity\u2019, while Musk starts poll on whether to reinstate Donald Trump"},
{"title": "Iranian protesters set fire to Ayatollah Khomeini\u2019s ancestral home", "header": "Social media images show what is now a museum commemorating the Islamic Republic founder ablaze as protests continue"},
{"title": "Two Canadian men charged with shooting animals at safari park", "header": "Mathieu Godard and Jeremiah Mathias-Polson accused of breaking into Parc Omega in Quebec and killing three wild boar and an elk"}
]
```

Scrapy documentation can be found here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/