# Reading csv with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to read the csv file but I am getting error that `TypeError: Request url must be str, got list` how to solve that kindly how to read list any suggestion recommend me

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import pandas as pd
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from io import open



class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'
    with open("category.csv") as file:
            start_urls=[line.strip() for line in file]               
            
    def start_requests(self):
            request=Request(url=self.start_urls,callback=self.parse)
            yield request
       
            
    def parse(self, response):
            pass
```

Comment: The error message is _very_ clear, but please provide the entire traceback anyways. You're passing a `list` (`self.start_urls`) as an argument which must be a `str`. Looks like you have a file containing URLs, one on each line, and want to send requests to each URL. You need to create a `Request` for each URL rather than pass a `list` of URLs to a single `Request`.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489650/spider-only-crawling-the-last-url-but-not-all/74498131#74498131 Should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the list and pass each url as a request.

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: now they show these error `raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:`

Comment: @developer that means you need to add `'https://'` or `'http:://`' to all of your urls or at least the ones that are missing it